# reauthenticating user is causing https.onCall() firestore cloud function not to receive authenticated user information

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Here's a real head-scratcher.  I have a cloud function that uses https.onCall().  This function call is triggered from a password protected area on my **Android application** (I'm using **Firestore** as my server).  In order to access this area, I force the user to re-enter their password which then calls FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().reauthenticate().

I've run the code that calls the https.onCall() cloud function without reauthentication and the function retains the user's authentication credentials, so I've narrowed it down to something when we reauthenticate.  Am I missing something? Do I have to do something to inform the cloud function of the authentication update?

The error message I was getting in the functions logs was:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of unidentified object".  Specifically this was happening when I was trying to get the uid of the authenticated user by the following:

```
const adminUID = context.auth.uid;
```

The assumption was that because I wasn't getting the above error, was because there was no authenticated data coming in via context.

To better clarify what's happening, here's my flow/process:

User selects "Account" from an options menu.  This launches a dialogFragment that asks for the user's password:

Button code in dialogFragment:

```
 loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //execute the loginReAuth method
            authenticateSession.loginAdminReAuth(adminEmailAddress, passwordField);
        }
    });
```

After the loginButton is selected and the user enter's their password, we are passing the data to the reauthenticate method:

Reauthenticate code:

```
public void loginAdminReAuth(final String email, TextView passwordText) {
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String password = passwordText.getText().toString();

    AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, password);
    user.reauthenticate(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AccountSettingsActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "re-authenticate:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getContext(), task.getException().getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

When the reauthentication is successful we run intent and take them to the AccountSettingsActivity.  Inside this activity I have the method: deleteAccount() which is triggered by a buttonClick in an alertDialog confirming the action.

Here's the buttonClick that triggers the method:

```
@Override
public void onDialogOKPressed(DialogFragment dialog) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    if (buttonSelected.equals("accountUpdateButton")) {
       //update code here.
    }
    else if (buttonSelected.equals("accountDeleteButton")) {
        deleteAccount(admin);
    }
}
```

Here's the deleteAccount() method that makes the cloud function request:

method that calls the cloud function:

```
private Task<String> deleteAccount(Admin selectedAdmin) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String selectedAdminJson;
    selectedAdminJson = gson.toJson(selectedAdmin);

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("selectedAdminJson", selectedAdminJson);

    return mFunctions
            .getHttpsCallable("deleteAccount")
            .call(data)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                @Override
                public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                    // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                    // has failed then getResult() will throw an Exception which will be
                    // propagated down.
                    Log.d(TAG, "results from deleteAccount: " + task.getResult().getData().toString());
                    String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                    return result;
                }
            });
}
```

Finally, here's the cloud firestore code that executes the request.
Cloud function https.onCall():

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

export = module.exports = functions.https
.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    //selectedAdminJson received from app client and converted to admin object class
    const selectedAdminJson = data.selectedAdminJson;
    const adminUID = context.auth.uid;

    //Error checking
    // Checking attribute.
    if (!(typeof selectedAdminJson === 'string') || selectedAdminJson.length === 0) {
        // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with ' +
            'one arguments "JSON object" containing selectedAdmin to add.');
    }
    // Checking that the user is authenticated OR if the calling adminID doesn't match the data received
    if (!context.auth) {
        // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
            'while authenticated.');
    }
    try {

        //METHODS EXECUTED HERE

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error removing adminUserGroup data: ", error);
    }

    // Returning result to the client.
    return {
        selectedAdminJson: "selectedAdminJson received and processing."
    };
});
```

One more piece.  This is part of my index.ts:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
admin.initializeApp();

if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME || process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === 'deleteAccount') {
    exports.deleteAccount = require('./deleteAccount');
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to illustrate what calls the `deleteAccount` method on Android, and under what circumstances.

Comment: Also, what's the error here? What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @DougStevenson.  The issue is that I'm getting null on context in the https.onCall() method.  In other words I'm not getting any of my authentication information that is sent from my Android client.

Comment: I'll edit my question for how I'm calling deleteAccount in a few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: Question edited for how deleteAccount() method is called. Please let me know if it's still not clear.  Thanks!

Comment: One more note:  Because the context is null (authentication missing) I cannot process my function (I'm checking for an authenticated user before allowing any deletions).

Comment: It's kind of difficult to track the order that your code is being called here.  How about reorganizing it sequentially, so that we can see the sequence of events here? Apparently there is a series of button presses here?

Comment: Okay. I just signed off for the evening from my computer. I'll make the changes in the morning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think I solved the problem. It looks like the issue was that I was logging the user out before the httpsCallable() could completely send the authentication information.

I was doing the following:

```
    deleteAccount(firebaseLocalCache.thisAdminFromCache());
    session.logoutUser();
```

Instead, I'll probably have to do some sort of continuation after the deleteAccount() method which returns a Task object. That way we logout the user ONLY after we get a response from the server.